# What is the difference between implicit constructor and explicit constructor?

Tags: java

Can some one explain me the difference between implicit constructor and explicit constructor in Java?

Comment: An implicit constructor is one that's not explicitly coded.

Answer (score 23):

**Explicit** means done by the programmer.
**Implicit** means done by the JVM or the tool , not the Programmer.

**For Example:**

> Java will provide us default constructor implicitly.Even if the programmer didn't write code for constructor, he can call default constructor.
>
> Explicit is opposite to this , ie. programmer has to write .

Default `constructor` is the constructor with `no arguments requested`. It is called implicitly when creating an instance.

The `no-args constructor` is called implicitly if you don't call one yourself, which is invalid if that constructor doesn't exist. The reason it is required to call a super constructor is that the superclass usually has some state it expects to be in after being `constructed`, which may include `private` variables that can't be set in a sub-class. If you don't call the `constructor`, it would leave the object in a `probably` invalid state, which can cause all kinds of problems